# Installing SIMS 3 from CD

Tags: installation

I've just gone over to ubuntu and need to install SIMS 3 for my daughter.
In Windows, it just pops up Run menu, but nothing when I put CD in ubuntu. Any ideas at all.

Answer (score 2):

The SIMS is great with Play-On-Linux

http://www.playonlinux.com/en

To get the latest developement version, open a terminal and type:

```
git clone https://github.com/PlayOnLinux/POL-POM-4
```

For the Oneiric version

Type the following commands:

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_oneiric.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

For the Natty version

Type the following commands:

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_natty.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

[DEB file](http://www.playonlinux.com/script_files/PlayOnLinux/4.0.16/PlayOnLinux_4.0.16.deb)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use [wine](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/wine). After you install it, open the CD folder with the file browser, and open the setup.exe (or whatever is is called) with "wine program launcher".